# Latest Partition of Mariadb table

Tags: mariadb, partitioning

How to check the latest partition of a table in mariadb?
I don't want to see all partition. Only latest one I want to get

Comment: "Check" for what?  Are you talking about `PARTITIONs` or something else?

Comment: I have resolved myself with below query.                                                                
 select TABLE_NAME,TABLE_SCHEMA,PARTITION_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS where TABLE_NAME='<table name>' order by PARTITION_NAME desc limit 1;

Comment: `partition_ordinal_position` would be safer to use in the `ORDER BY` -- it does not depend on your naming condition.

Comment: Many Thanks Rick.Will try this too